# Hide ad when keyboard is open in Ionic

Tags: cordova, admob, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ads

I have an admob advertisement at the bottom of my app. When I click on the input box in the footer of my page, not only does the keyboard pop up but the advertisement does too. How do I hide the advertisement so i just have keyboard and input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide any html element when the keyboard shows up you just have to add the 'hide-on-keyboard-open' class on the element.

[From Ionic docs:](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/)

> To hide an element when the keyboard is open, add the class hide-on-keyboard-open.
>
> `<div class="hide-on-keyboard-open">
>      <div id="google-map"></div>
>     </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your config.xml:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/>
```